# Disable virtual menus

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[Please help clean up the tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disable+or+virtual+or+menus):

- <s>[disable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disable)</s> **now removed**
- <s>[virtual](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual)</s> **now removed**
- <s>[menus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/menus)</s> **now removed**

I've already been working on these for some time.

Comment: Shouldn't it be voted on, before the [tag:status-planned] is added? ;)

Comment: @CanadianLuke It was voted on, by me. The result was unanimous.

Comment: MOD POWER ABUSE! I'M TELLING THE OTHER MODS ON YOU! :-P

Comment: @Canadian Luke, [is your caps lock key stuck?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8175/add-a-no-caps-lock-message-hint-check-on-the-website)

Comment: @smc NO, BUT NOW IT'S SO MUCH EASIER TO TYPE! THANKS, [BASH.ORG](http://bash.org/?835030)!

Comment: [tag:disable] is now empty too.

Comment: @CanadianLuke So you mean to say that how mods can bindingly close questions is "mod power abuse"? What about Mjolnir power abuse by non-moderators? Okay, if this was heavily downvoted, then maybe different things would have happened.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I just like joking around. It's not abuse unless they abuse it. It's part of our job as mods to do it (I'm not a mod on SU, but on another SE site), unless the issue can be fixed quickly.

Comment: All three are now clear.

Comment: @Cfinley Thanks!

Comment: @OliverSalzburg For the sake of making it look complete, could you add ***now removed*** to [tag:virtual]?? Or am I being too picky ;p

Comment: @ṧнʊ&#223; I would, but it's hard on the phone. Suggest an edit maybe

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I have enough rep to edit now :) Didn't think of that before because a lot of meta posts can't be edited by non-mods. BTW, I can tell you're using your phone because you used the `&#223` for my name (as you said in your meta post :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg You can't suggest edits to posts on meta. This is why I rely on flags to make minor edits to certain posts (such as retagging).

Comment: @ṧнʊß You can edit meta posts directly if you have enough rep; you just can't suggest edits if you don't have enough rep.