# ACTIVATE QUALITY FILTERS FOR QUESTIONS IN ALL CAPS!

Tags: feature-request

Irritating isn't it? The [most recent example](https://superuser.com/revisions/776133/1) that appears in [previous feature request](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8175/235569) about the help pages. Is funny that isn't enabled here either. Can we enable it?

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps

Comment: This is mostly the same as the first bullet point in the previous question.

Comment: @slhck that question is about the help page, mine is focused to a single point, not all of them.

Comment: No, not exclusively: *"When a user clicks 'Post Question' and all the 'checks' happen (…) make sure there are at least 10 or so lowercase characters, or a percent of the text is lowercase, or similar."*

Comment: @slhck when you mark that one as "status-completed" what exactly you are marking as done? The help page thingy? The quality check thingy? What exactly?

Comment: Not sure why you're worrying about this now, but if either of these is implemented (whenever that may happen), the other question would be marked as completed.

Comment: I sure wonder why you didn't capitalize `[DUPLICATE]` in the title.